# microsoft-graph-client throws '#<GraphError>' error on API call

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, adal.js, microsoft-graph-sdks

I would like to consume the Graph API from my Node backend. First I get an access token from [adal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node) by calling the `acquireTokenWithClientCredentials` method. So my token response would be

[image: token response]

I install the [@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) package and tried to follow the guide from here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/samples/node/main.js . For the `isomorphic-fetch` import I installed the [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) package.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  // ...
  const session: TokenResponse = await authenticationService.getSession(); // call the 'acquireTokenWithClientCredentials' function

  const client: Client = Client.init({
    authProvider: (done) => {
      done(null, session.accessToken);
    },
  });

  try {
    await client.api('/me').get();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

The API call throws an exception. But I can't figure out what's wrong because the error only logs

```
(node:20561) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<GraphError>
```

What is wrong or missing? Please let me know if you need more information. But I hope that my description should be enough for reproduction :) Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

The application does not sign in as a user and should run as a background service. So maybe I can't access `/me` because the application is not a user. But when I update `/me` to `/users` (this endpoint should work) then I still get the same error.

So my current access token when accessing `/users` is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use [Client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get access token for `/me` endpoint. You should use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)(`acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode`) instead. Then you can call `/me` for the signed-in user.

If you must use client credential flow, you should call `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` for a specific user.

Besides, if you want to call Microsoft Graph API, the value of resource which you used to get access token should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

```
var resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com';
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. Would you mind explaining why I should use `acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode` instead? Where does the authorizationcode come from? And it's expecting a redirect uri but I use a Node backend ...

Comment: edit: my application is running as a service without a user so I think my code is right but I can't access `me` because the service is no user. But when I change `/me` to `/users` I still get that error

Comment: @Question3r I see. Then you should use client credential flow. What is the value of resource?

Comment: @Question3r Did you add user id/userPrincipalName along with users?(`/users/{id | userPrincipalName}`)

Comment: @ Tony Ju I updated my question, the last picture shows that I'm using `https://graph.microsoft.com` as a resource now. And no, I didn't add a user id. I would like to list all users because I only use a demo account, there would be only me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204769/discussion-between-tony-ju-and-question3r).